# Passing integer variables into SQL statement from another form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm working with a school project where we are supposed to build a simple booking system that utilizes SQL database. Used language is C# and environment Visual Studio Community 2017. I'm trying to build a function where user selects a row from dataGridView1 and clicks 'Add new invoice button'. The booking_id is extracted from dataGridView1 and passed to Form2 where booking-related data is searched with booking_id. This data is then presented in dataGridView2 which lists all services included in the one user-specified booking.

Database contains three relevant tables; Booking, Service and BoughServices.

1. `Booking` contains column `booking_id` (INT)
2. `Services` contains columns `service_id` (INT), `name` (VARCHAR) and `price` (INT)
3. `BoughtServices`, contains columns `Booking.booking_id` (INT),
   `Service.service_id` (INT) and `amount` (INT)

Code on Form1:

```
// Establish a class for data.
public static class DataToForm2
{
    public static int booking_id;
}

// User clicks button 'Add new invoice'.
private void button_CreateInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    //Note: CurrentRow.Cells[0] contains booking_id.
    DataToForm2.booking_id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
    f2.Show();
}
```

Code on Form2:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Set SQL query string.
        string query = "SELECT Service.name, Services.price, BoughtServices.amount " +
            "FROM Service " +
                "INNER JOIN Service.service_id ON BoughtServices.service_id " +
                "INNER JOIN Bookings ON Bookings.booking_id = BoughtServices.booking_id " +
            "WHERE " +
                "Booking.booking_id = @booking_id";  

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        // Set query parameters.
        command.Parameters.Add("@booking_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Form1.DataToForm2.booking_id;

        // Run SQL query
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

However, this approach is non-functional and crashes with an error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@booking_id`. I have spent an increasing number of hours to figure this out and find solution from tutorials but so far they all have failed. Interestigly, everything is working just fine when I add booking_id directly to SQL statement. In otherwords, `WHERE Booking.booking_id = 2` works like a charm.

Could someone help me and propose how I should format my code so that I am able to perform desired actions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to add Parameters and fill in the values you said you were going to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost right. The only problem is the SqlDataAdapter that receives the sql string and not the command where you have defined the parameter. Just change

```
// Run SQL query
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
```

As you can see there is a [SqlDataAdapter's constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1(v=vs.110).aspx) that receives a SqlCommand where you could define parameters and set the connection.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much for your help Steve!

Answer (score -1):

You're using the parameterized SQL query incorrectly. It functions more like string.Replace than an assignment. Try

```
command.Parameters.Add("@booking_id", 
Form1.DataToForm2.booking_id);
```

Comment: The syntax used is perfectly valid.